# c# Regex predication giving an error

Tags: c#, regex

I am using `regex` code to find contact match in my windows phone application and it works good but gives an error sometimes `"Values cannot be null"`.

```
try {
    var l = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in listobj)
    l.Add(item.FirstName);

    var digitMap = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
        { 1, "" },
        { 2, "[abcABC]" },
        { 3, "[defDEF]" },
        { 4, "[ghiGHI]" },
        { 5, "[jklJKL]" },
        { 6, "[mnoMNO]" },
        { 7, "[pqrsPQRS]" },
        { 8, "[tuvTUV]" },
        { 9, "[wxyzWXYZ]" },
        { 0, "" },
    };

    var enteredDigits = str;
    var charsAsInts = enteredDigits.ToCharArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()));
    var regexBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var val in charsAsInts)
        regexBuilder.Append(digitMap[val]);

    var pattern = regexBuilder.ToString();
    //append a ".*" to the end of the regex to make it "StartsWith", beginning for "EndsWith", or both for "Contains";
    pattern = ".*" + pattern + ".*";

    var matchingNames = l.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, pattern));
    SearchListbox.ItemsSource = listobj.FindAll(x=>x.PhoneNumbers.Contains(str) | x.FirstName.Contains(matchingNames.FirstOrDefault()));

} catch (Exception e) {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

I think when no contacts match it throws an error, also it doesn't show all the matches until, whole name matches.

What's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell me first please what are you actualy trying to do? This looks very convoluted to me for something that should be simple

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no match, matchingNames is null then matchingNames.FirstOrDefault() is also null

So here you'r doing String.Contains(null) => Exception

you see ? something like that :

```
if (matchingNames == null)    
{    
    //Search just in phoneNumbers    
    SearchListbox.ItemsSource = listobj.FindAll(x=>x.PhoneNumbers.Contains(str));    
}    
else    
{    
    //Search both    
    SearchListbox.ItemsSource = listobj.FindAll(x=>x.PhoneNumbers.Contains(str) |  x.FirstName.Contains(matchingNames.FirstOrDefault()));    
}
```

For your second problem try to remove completely the matchingNames and l variables :

```
try {
    var digitMap = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
        { 1, "" },
        { 2, "[abcABC]" },
        { 3, "[defDEF]" },
        { 4, "[ghiGHI]" },
        { 5, "[jklJKL]" },
        { 6, "[mnoMNO]" },
        { 7, "[pqrsPQRS]" },
        { 8, "[tuvTUV]" },
        { 9, "[wxyzWXYZ]" },
        { 0, "" },
    };

    var enteredDigits = str;
    var charsAsInts = enteredDigits.ToCharArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()));
    var regexBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var val in charsAsInts)
        regexBuilder.Append(digitMap[val]);

    var pattern = regexBuilder.ToString();
    //append a ".*" to the end of the regex to make it "StartsWith", beginning for "EndsWith", or both for "Contains";
    pattern = ".*" + pattern + ".*";

    SearchListbox.ItemsSource = listobj.FindAll(x=>x.PhoneNumbers.Contains(str) | Regex.isMatch(x.FirstName, pattern));

} catch (Exception e) {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Please state what you suggest to solve that issue. This isn't an answer to the question yet.

Comment: @Benji_9989 That solved all my problems :) Thank you